# how to mask all the div items in single parent div in css3

Tags: html, css

I created a list of animations through CSS animations and animations are like left to right and i.e object comes from left and stays in box(parent div) some time then goes to right in window. I did list of animations like these example. But I don't wanted to show the animations out of the box, animations  should be visible in the box only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this is use `overflow: hidden;` on the parent element to mask the elements outside the box

Comment: @chandru you welcome, also I saw your profile, you should accept the answers which are correct, including this one, it will help future visitors to refer